# css: style all a elements before hovered

Tags: css, styles, hover, element

I'm trying to style all elements before hovered (from the left side).

Here is my code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LgKkU/467/)

[CSS]:

```
a,
a:link,
a:hover,
a:visited {
    /* ... */
    color: #222;
}

a:hover, 
a:hover ~ a {
    color: #f00;
}
```

[HTML]:

```
<a href="#">text1|</a>
<a href="#">text2|</a>
<a href="#">text3|</a>
```

All I've done is hovering from the right side (after hovered element), but I want it from the left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A small change with the html and css can satisfy your requirement.

HTML:

```
<div><a href="#">this/</a><a href="#">line/</a><a href="#">is/</a><a href="#">hovering/</a><a href="#">from/</a><a href="#">left/</a><div>
```

CSS:

```
a,
a:link,
a:hover,
a:visited,
div {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14pt;
    background: #def;
    color: #222;
}
div:hover a{
    color: #f00;
}
a:hover ~ a {
    color: #222;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YKRZt/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to style all elements differently?

you can select elements by nth-child selector.

Example:

```
a:nth-child(1){}
a:first-child+a{} or a:nth-child(1) + a /* Second Element */
a:last-child{} /*select last child, Works in ie8+, webkit, moz, o */
```

Comment: No, I dont want to style them differently.
Its just normal hover behaviour for all elements before hovered.

Im tying to create custom linked url 
f.e. http://jsfiddle.net/LgKkU/487/